# How to delete records permanently in case of linked tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-delete, relationships

Let's say I have these 2 tables QuesType and Ques:-

```
QuesType

QuestypeID|QuesType      |Active
------------------------------------
101       |QuesType1     |True
102       |QuesType2     |True
103       |XXInActiveXX  |False



Ques

QuesID|Ques|Answer|QUesTypeID|Active
------------------------------------
1     |Ques1|Ans1 |101     |True
2     |Ques2|Ans2 |102     |True
3     |Ques3|Ans3 |101     |True
```

In the QuesType Table:-
QuesTypeID is a Primary key

In the Ques Table:-
QuesID is a Primary key and QuesType ID is the Foreign Key that refernces QuesTypeID from QuesType Table

Now I am unable to delete records from QuesType Table, I can only make QuesType inactive by setting Active=False.
I am unable to delete QuesTypes permanently because of the Foreign key relation it has with Ques Table. So , I just set the
column Active=false and those Questypes then don't show on my grid when its bound.

What I want to do is be able to delete any QuesType permamnently. Now it can only be deleted if its not being used anywhere 
in the Ques table, right?

So to delete any QuesType permanently I thought this is what I could do:-

In the grid that displays QuesTypes, I have this check box for Active and a button for delete.What I thought was, when a user
makes some QuesType inactive then OnCheckChanged() event will run and that will have the code to delete all the Questions
in Ques table that are using that QuesTypeID. Then on the QuesType grid, that QuesType would show as Deactivated and only 
then can a user delete it permanently.

Am I thinking correctly?

Currently in my DeleteQuesType Stored Procedure what I am doing is:-

Setting the Active=false and
Setting QuesTye= some string like XXInactiveXX

Is there any other way?

**edit
What if I want to implement that way only, like first get the user to deactivate the QuesType and only if it's deactivated that the user can delete it permanently. Is that correct logic?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is put the

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

clause on your foreign key constraint. This will automatically delete rows from your Ques table when its corresponding QuesType row is deleted.

Comment: um ok but what if I want to implement that way only, like first get the user to deactivate the QuesType and only if it's deactivated that the user can delete it permanently. Is that correct logic?

Comment: You already have an active column, just query this to make sure it's false before deleting. You could do this automatically using a trigger, but if you're a beginner then I'd probably advise against this.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete only the `QuesTypes` deactivated.

Before deleting a `QuesType` you'll have to query the database and see if `QuesType.Active = false`. If yes, you can delete all rows from the child table that reference that `QuesType.Id` (this is known as a **cascade** delete). You can also set a null value on QuesTypeID column in the child rows.

Read [this book online](http://books.google.com/books?id=ekEt972gEDIC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=cascade+set+null+on+child+row+sql+server&source=bl&ots=zn410KXT5z&sig=5FNs8LbZWZU4Uh4-mJGbFRZ8x8k&hl=en&ei=7tEkTdGVLsT7lwew6sjZAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=cascade%20set%20null%20on%20child%20row%20sql%20server&f=false) to learn about the ON DELETE CASCADE | SET NULL clause. This clause will enable you to do what you want.